# App crash when setting progressBar visibilty to gone

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, progress-bar

Hi i'm having this problem that i simply don't understand i have a tabbed activity and each fragment has a webview in it and webviews have a progress bar that shows when they are loading but when i set the progress bar visibilty to gone the app crash the AVD log shows no exceptions but when i've commented

```
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

it simply doesn't crash but the progress bar is always there if anyone can tell me where is the problem i'll be so thankful,thank you this is my code

```
 package org.lsvbdarija.app;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.net.NetworkInfo;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;

    /**
     * Created by Anas on 20/06/2016.
     */

    public class SocialFragment extends Fragment {

    public WebView mWebView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
                case 1: {
                    webViewGoBack();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (!haveNetworkConnection()) {
            getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
        }

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.social_layout, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.lsvbdarija.com/search/label/%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%88%D9%85");

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                String url2="http://www.lsvbdarija.com/";
                // all links  with in ur site will be open inside the webview
                //links that start ur domain example(http://www.example.com/)
                if (url != null && url.startsWith(url2)){
                    return false;
                }
                // all links that points outside the site will be open in a normal android browser
                else  {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                }
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

              //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }


        });

        return v;

    }


    private void webViewGoBack() {
        mWebView.goBack();
    }


    private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }



}
```

Comment: There has to be an exception in logcat if the app crashes. Make sure you don't have log filtering set up to where you can't see the exception.

Comment: there is absolutely nothing if you want i can copy the log :/

Comment: if there's "absolutely nothing", that's very suspicious. If you're using Android Studio, make sure that on the logcat tab of the Android Monitor tool window you have "No filters" showing in the top-right drop-down box. If the log shows your app starting and ending without an exception, then yes, please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the progress bar defined in the fragment layout or the activity layout? If it is in the fragment then it should be

progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

Answer (score -1):

Replace your get activity().findviewbyid() to v.findviewbyid();